# why are we adding quotation mark around the name of the variable after !=?

Tags: python, string, loops, input, user-input

In line 5 , what is the difference and the purpose of using `" "` around the variables's name?

```
while target_guess != "target_guess":   #with quotation.
```

What is wrong with using

```
while target_guess != target_guess:    #without quotation.
```

```
print("Enter the integer for the player to guess.")
target_guess = int(input())
my_guess = int(input())
counter = 0
while target_guess != "target_guess":
    counter +=1
    my_guess = int(input())
    if my_guess > target_guess:
        print("Too high - try again:")
        my_guess = int(input())
    elif my_guess < target_guess:
        print("Too low - try again:")
        my_guess = int(input())
    else: 
        break


print("You guessed it in " + str(counter) + " tries")
```

Comment: Both are equally nonsensical to me. What are you trying to accomplish with that condition? `target_guess != target_guess` is just a funny way to say `False`, and `target_guess != "target_guess"` is just a funny way to say `True`.

Comment: It's completely impossible for `target_guess != "target_guess"` to ever return `False`, since `target_guess` is an `int`, and `"target_guess"` is a string. It's unclear why that's in the code at all instead of just `while True`, which would function totally identically.

Comment: @Brian but when I use False instead of "target_guess", my code will not go through the loop. I am only getting the right result when I use target_guess != "target_guess", neither True nor False is giving me the right answer.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you so much, Yes I used while True and it gave me the same output. Can you please explain it to me more? I am new to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Quotation marks indicate that it is not a variable name, but a string value.

`target_guess != "target_guess"` checks whether the value of the variable `target_guess` is not equal to the string `"target_guess"`, while `target_guess != target_guess` checks whether the value of the variable `target_guess` is not equal to the value of the variable `target_guess` (which is a nonsensical check, as it is the same variable, so the values are equal).

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation, I understand the difference now. so we are sitting while loop to true so it can run, is that right?

Comment: Yes, if the condition in the while loop always returns `True`, you essentially create an infinite loop. The loop then stops if the `break` statement is reached. Note that you don't have to think of a comparison that always returns `True` (such as `target_guess == target_guess`, you can simply write `while True:`.